# Was Grimiore Heart aware that Zeref was still alive?

Tags: fairy-tail

I was recently reading an article on Fairy Tail on the Tower of Heaven when I remembered some events that transpired during the Tenrou Tree Arc that was...

> It was revealed that Zeref was still alive

And the purpose for Grimiore Heart working on the Tower of Heaven was...

> To restore life to someone who is deceased at the cost of someone else's life or in this case to sacrifice Erzas life for Zerefs as what was revealed in the anime

Based on this information, does this mean that Grimiore Heart was unaware of that Zeref was still alive and if they were what would have been the most obvious motive for using the Tower of Heaven which on the Fairy Tail wikia is described as:

> The Tower of Heaven (楽園の塔 Rakuen no Tō), also known as the R-System, is a taboo Magic Item that can be used to restore life to a deceased person.

I would prefer an in cannon answer preferably from reliable sources. An answer would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I don't think Grimoire Heart was involved in building the tower of heavens. At all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they were since Ultear possessed Jellal to do it while he was under the impression that she was the "Ghost of Zeref".

Answer (score 1):

Ultear controlled Jellal to build the R-System, so the Magic Council focuses on him and not on the Grimoire Heart, who could then move in the shadows to continue their search for Zeref. (Tower of Heaven Arc)

So to answer your question, Yes, Grimoire was aware Zeref was alive and used Jellal as a decoy to search for him. After finding him launching an attack on Tenrou Island (Tenrou Arc)